# Azure Geomentry type throws exception Could not load file or assembly microsoft.sqlserver.types, Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: azure, filenotfoundexception, sqlexception

I'm hosting Restful service on Azure. It worked fine. But today I obtained that methods with Geometry type using throws an exception. What interesting that I didn't update anything.

I used NuGet Package with reference to microsoft.sqlserver.types, Version=10.0.0.0 and it worked fine.

Exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 1. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at ...
```

I tried to reference microsoft.sqlserver.types, Version=11.0.0.0 but no success.

Could not find any question related with this issue. Is someone have this issue? Any solution? And what happened at Azure that it does not work today.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution:

Install "Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065 as startup task.

Copy SQLSysClrTypes.msi in Startup folder in project and create startup.cmd file in the same folder. Note: should be "Copy to Output directory" = "Copy always"

ServiceDefenition.csdef

```
...
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup\Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />      
</Startup>
...
```

Startup.cmd

```
REM Install Sql Sys Clr Types

cd /d "%~dp0"

start /w msiexec /i SQLSysClrTypes.msi /qn
```

And it works now.

Hope this save time for someone. Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

The ADO Team now has released an official NuGet package to help resolve this.

1. Install the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/).
2. Ensure the appropriate version of the native SqlServerSpatial110.dll assembly is copied to the output directory and deployed with your application. Steps on how to do this are included in a ReadMe.txt file that will open in Visual Studio when you install the package.

Please [read all about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx) at the official blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll, which contains the spatial data types, has been upgraded from version 10.0 to version 11.0. Custom applications that reference this assembly may fail.

Here are several solutions
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/dn236441(v=sql.120).aspx

1. You can work around this issue in your code by calling the GetSqlBytes method, instead of the Get methods listed above, to retrieve CLR SQL Server system types, as shown in the following example

   ```
     string query = "SELECT [SpatialColumn] FROM [SpatialTable]";
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
     { 
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 

           conn.Open(); 
           SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

           while (reader.Read()) 
           { 
                 // In version 11.0 only 
                 SqlGeometry g = SqlGeometry.Deserialize(reader.GetSqlBytes(0)); 

                 // In version 10.0 or 11.0 
                 SqlGeometry g2 = new SqlGeometry(); 
                 g.Read(new BinaryReader(reader.GetSqlBytes(0).Stream)); 
           } 
     }
   ```
2. You can work around this issue by using assembly redirection in the application configuration file, as shown in the following example:

   ```
    < assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        ...
        < dependentAssembly>
            < assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
            < bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
        < /dependentAssembly>
        ...
    < /assemblyBinding>
   ```
3. You can work around this issue in your connection string by specifying a value of "SQL Server 2012" for the "Type System Version" attribute to force SqlClient to load version 11.0 of the assembly. This connection string attribute is available only in .NET 4.5 and above.